# Dual Boot not working

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, grub

I had Windows 10 installed on my computer, I shrunk the partition it was installed on then installed linux on the new partition.  Now when I turn on my computer I see GRUB and the only option is my linux distro and the windows installation is not in the menu.  How can I add the windows 10 installation as an option in the GRUB menu?

Comment: How did you install? Are both UEFI or both BIOS? What brand/model system? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred
1. How: I made a live USB, booted with the USB, used GParted to make a new partition in the drive (about 24gb), installed linux and GRUB onto the new partition.
2. Windows 10 is BIOS and linux was installed in "Compatibility mode" so that it would be compatible with the booting already in place.
3. "ppa" is not an option at boot. The GRUB menu only shows for a second or two, but the only options besides booting into the OS are a. Advanced Options for Linux and b. System setup.

Comment: You do not install grub to a partition. If you install to a NTFS partition you break Windows. And grub recommends you not install to partition as it is fragile, but some third party tools suggest you do that. BIOS/MBR systems only boot from a drive's MBR. If only one MBR/drive, you have to install grub to drive to dual boot. But Windows 10 makes it difficult as it turns on fast start up with updates & then grub will not boot it. Make sure you have both Windows repair/recovery drive & Ubuntu live installer to change MBR to Windows when grub will not boot it and then restore grub.

Comment: @oldfred so in my case, since I already broke Windows in order to dual boot I must now create a Windows bootable USB, use it to boot Windows and then the Windows bootloader will become the default bootloader and it will give me the options of booting from Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows only boots Windows. It normally does not correctly see Linux partitions. And with BIOS Windows since Windows 7, it updates partition table, but forgets to include your Linux logical partitions. Be sure to have good backups. Part of why UEFI is better as at least then it does not erase partitions.

Comment: @oldfred I am very solution based so I am trying to understand your very knowledgable comment as a solution.  Are you saying that if I create a Windows 10 live USB drive and boot with that into recovery mode that the USB will recover the Windows bootloader and set it as the default bootloader which will be able to boot Windows 10 because "Windows boots Windows" and the Windows boot loader will ALSO be able to boot the linux OS?

Comment: Generally you want to use Windows to make Windows repairs. Only a few minor fixes to Windows can be done from Linux. Be sure to boot Windows flash drive in same mode as install, or UEFI or BIOS mode. But Windows does not see nor correct work with Linux. Except new Windows 10 that can have Linux installed inside it. Windows will not boot Windows, you have to have grub in MBR, and Windows hibernation off.

Comment: @oldfred 1. Create bootable Windows 10 USB 2. Boot from Windows 10 USB and choose Recovery Mode 3.Repair Windows Installation 4. Boot from bootable GRUB USB and install GRUB 5. GRUB will now list Windows 10 and Linux as options.  Are 1-5 what you are telling me to do to fix this?

Comment: Yes. And if BIOS, you may have to regularly do this as Windows updates turn fast start up back on. And then grub will not boot Windows. If UEFI, you just have to directly boot Windows entry from UEFI, fix it and then set grub back to first in boot order.

Comment: @oldfred I made a bootable Windows 10 USB and booted from it.  I chose 'Repair Mode' then Troubleshoot > Startup Repair but then a screen comes up saying "Startup Repair couldn't repair your PC" so I cannot reach step 3.  Also in the troubleshoot menu are "Command Prompt", "Uninstall Updates", "UEFI Firmware Settings", "System Restore" and "System Image Recovery" What should I do?  I have backups of everything so I could reinstall Windows if need be, maybe I installed it on the wrong partition.  How can I see what is on the partition before I install an OS to it?

Comment: How you boot Install or repair media, UEFI or BIOS is how it installs or repairs. But if not in same mode as install, it will not work. If install is BIOS, did you boot repair in UEFI, so it gave error?  UEFI/BIOS should show two boot options for USB flash drive. Have not installed Windows since XP, so do not know details. BIOS partitions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & UEFI partitions 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: @oldfred I ended up using a Virtualbox installation to have both systems.